# NPOI xls: calculated end index (x) is out of allowable range (y..y+2)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi

I always get an exception when writing to newly created file. I get this exception even if provided sheet is empty. Workbook without sheets saves without a problem.

This exception shows for an empty sheet.

> Additional information: calculated end index (1932) is out of
>   allowable range (1908..1910)

I'm using NOPI.dll ver.2.1.3.1 http://npoi.codeplex.com/
File I try to create is .xls (Excel 97-2003)

**filePath** in code bolow has a value @"C:\TB\Report.xls"

My code

```
public void Generate()
    {
        HSSFWorkbook newWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        ISheet newSheet = newWorkBook.CreateSheet("Main");
        newWorkBook.Add(newSheet); 

        using (FileStream fileOut = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            newWorkBook.Write(fileOut);
        }
    }
```

File is created but it's empty.

When creating xls with sheet that has rows and columns the result is the same except the numbers in exception are higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using ISheet instead of HSSFSheet. Example shown in the documentation used ISheet but it was incorrect.

Correct code:

```
public void Generate()
{
    HSSFWorkbook newWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet newSheet = (HSSFSheet)newWorkBook.CreateSheet("Main");

    var headerRow = newSheet.CreateRow(0);
    var headerCell = headerRow.CreateCell(0);
    headerCell.SetCellValue("Something");

    using (FileStream fileOut = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        newWorkBook.Write(fileOut);
    }
}
```